# Extracting data from a Magento collection. I have it broken down to an array but trying to call it breaks the page

Tags: php, arrays, magento

I'm working on a script that will give a Magento user directions after selecting warehouse pickup (a plugin option). I already have the rest built. I'm simply missing one variable I need to call on success.phtml (the warehouse ID). The variable is tied to orders via stock_id.

**This produces an array:** I'm using $order successfully to pull the rest of the info I need for the script.

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
$items = $order->getItemsCollection();
```

**A shortened version of this array:** can be printed with print_r($items->getData());

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 223
            [stock_id] => 15
            [base_discount_refunded] => 
        )

)
```

When I try to pull the data that I want out:

```
echo $items[0]['stock_id']; //the page breaks here and stops the page abruptly...
```

the page breaks and any logic that should take place after is ignored. What would cause this? I tried braking variables I'm calling in other similar arrays. None of my tests have replicated the page breaking. Why is this specific one breaking the page instead of returning 15?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try enumerating $items using var_export in your page, instead of print_r so you can see them as they truly exist:

```
foreach ($items as $item)
{
   var_export($item->debug());
}
```

This will provide you with the results. Items is an object populated with more objects, not an array and should be treated as such. Try using

```
$itemId = $item->getStockId();
```

or

```
$itemId = $item->getData('stock_id');
```

Both accomplish the same thing.

FYI.. the debug() function shows relevant info and its built into magento for use with all mage objects.

EDIT: Try this:

```
echo $items[0]->getData('stock_id');
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried echo $items[0]->getData('stock_id'); it breaks the page as well. Trying the first part next.

Comment: Going to accept! Thank you very much for your help. I got the number I needed with **$itemId = $item->getStockId();** after **foreach ($items as $item)**. though I am a little confused as to why and how it should look all together.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `$items` is not an array, it is an object of `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Item_Collection`. This should work:

```
$data = $items->getData();
echo $data[0]['stock_id'];
```

But using the enumeration interface of the collection, like already mentioned, would be much cleaner. Take a look at http://alanstorm.com/magento_collections.

You should also check your PHP configuration, to get more information on such errors. Take a look at http://alanstorm.com/magento_exception_handling_developer_mode.

Comment: Thanks! I see how this makes a lot more sense. Is this a better approach than above? If so why?

Comment: No, this is just for explanation. Use `foreach` to iterate over your `$items` collection and then going forward with the `$item` like mentioned above. Because this is much cleaner, instead of using the data of the collection directly.